# updating my database values through php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to do a Registration that the users will put their name password and their answers to some questions and then an admin will manually answer to it if it's accepted.I did the system that loads their name password and answers in the database,and I also ran the things that will show the answers to the admin,but I can't figure a way to change a value just for one user not for all of them,I will leave you my codes and everything over here.

Here is my admin.viewapplications.php code
(Here,it shows everything fine,but I can't figure a way that the button to act just for one id not for all)

```
<?php
//include(__DIR__ . "/signup.php");
include("../resources/config.php");

//$name = $_POST['Name'];
//$mg = $_POST['MG'];
//$pg = $_POST['PG'];
//$rk = $_POST['RK'];

$sql = "SELECT id, name, tutorial, MG, PG, RK FROM rp_users WHERE tutorial = 2";
//$tutorial = "SELECT tutorial FROM rp_users";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
//$result2 = mysql_query($tutorial);
//$value = mysql_fetch_object($result2)
/*if($result)
{
    echo "Succes";
}
else
{
    die(mysql_error());
}*/

//if($value > 1)
//
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    //$tutorial = row["tutorial"];
//f($tutorial == 2)
//}
$id = $row["id"];
$name = $row["name"];
$mg = $row["MG"];
$pg = $row["PG"];
$rk =  $row["RK"];

echo "ID: " . $id."<br> <br>";
echo "Nume: " . $name."<br> <br>";
echo "MG: " . $mg."<br> <br>";
echo "PG: " . $pg."<br> <br>";
echo "RK: " . $rk."<br> <br>";
echo '<form action="./?p=applicationaccept" method="POST">';
echo '<input type="submit" name="accept" value="Accepta">';
echo '</form><br>';
echo '<form action="./?p=applicationdeny" method="POST">';
echo '<input type="submit" name="deny" value="Respinge">';
echo '</form><br> <br> <br>';
}
//}
//

?>
```

And here is my applicationaccept.php

```
<?php
include("../admin/admin.viewapplications.php");
include("../resources/config.php");

$iduser = $id;


$sql = "UPDATE rp_users SET tutorial=0";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result)
{
    echo "Succes";
}
else
{
    die(mysql_error());
}
/*while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

}*/
?>
```

Comment: This title isn't helpful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As of my understanding of your question if your form action is `applicationaccept.php` and you are trying to update for one user in `applicationaccept.php` file, try this:

```
<?php
include("../admin/admin.viewapplications.php");
include("../resources/config.php");

$iduser = $_POST["id"]; // pass id as parameter in form


$sql = "UPDATE rp_users SET tutorial=0";// change this line to following line
 $sql = "UPDATE rp_users SET tutorial=0 where id=$iduser";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result)
{
    echo "Succes";
}
else
{
die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

**Be aware your code is vulnerable**

Comment: It gives me this error  - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Have you passed the id as parameter from form ?

Comment: Yes,I did it in another way,I added a text thing where you need to put the ID and then I passed that,thanks anyways.

Comment: @user634462 you can `var_dump($_POST["id"])`. i think you don't send it.

Comment: @user634462 and if you have own structure for using `$id` change `$sql` to this one: `$sql = "UPDATE rp_users SET tutorial=0 where id=$id"`. It works.

Comment: `$sql = "UPDATE rp_users SET tutorial=0 where id=$iduser"` is missing closure here and is causing an error for them.

Comment: @SachinAryal I know your answer was accepted, but you still haven't fixed the typo you made. Future visitors to the answer will think your code is correct, which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is a simple UPDATE to your MySQL database..
but make sure you format the PHP code you're using otherwise it'll give you an ERROR!
Also you have to use 'mysqli' now in PHP!

```
 <?php

 $someID = '1';

 $sql = "UPDATE `rp_users` SET `tutorial`= '0' WHERE `id` = $someID";

 $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
 if($result)
 {
     echo "Success";
 }
   else
 {
   echo ("Error");
 } 

?>
```

BTW I forgot to mntion the '$link' is the connection to your database!